# Multiple assignment from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, is it possible to make multiple assignments in the following manner (or, rather, is there a shorthand):

```
import random

def random_int():
    return random.randint(1, 100)

a, b = # for each variable assign the return values from random_int
```

Comment: create a dictionary, add the variables to it and return the dictionary,then you can access the dictionary individual variable in caller program

Comment: @Allen I was wondering whether there is a shorthand.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do...

Comment: This will be the best way to return multiple values e,g: `return {'a':a, 'b':b }`

Comment: In my test, if you have exactly as many variables as items in your return, then it works.

Comment: Shorthand for what exactly?  your function returns a single int so what else would you do but assign a single variable? If you were actually using a function that returned multiple numbers then use a dict or just a list and index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to assign different return values from two different calls to your random function or a single value to two variables generated by a single call to the function.

For the former, use tuple unpacking

```
t = (2,5)
a,b = t #valid!

def random_int():
    return random.randint(1, 100)
#valid: unpack a 2-tuple to a 2-tuple of variables
a, b = random_int(), random_int()
#invalid: tries to unpack an int as a 2-tuple
a, b = random_int()

#valid: you can also use comprehensions
a, b = (random_int() for i in range(2))
```

For the second, you can chain assignments to assign the same values to multiple variables.

```
#valid, "normal" way
a = random_int()
b = a

#the same, shorthand
b = a = random_int()
```

Comment: It seems that there is no built-in shorthand, thus I go for I go for `a, b = (random_int() for i in range(2))`

Answer (score 1):

In my test, if you have exactly as many variables as items in your return, then it works.

```
def algo():
    return range(5)

a5 = algo()                       # works
b1,b2,b3,b4,b5 = algo()           # works
c1,c2,c3 = algo()                 # doesn't work
d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6 = algo()        # doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 0):

dictionaries are a good way, or else you can use namedtuples from collections in python, try something like this, you will receive multiple call results in a single variable say a

```
num = namedtuple("num", "b c d")
a = num(random_int(),random_int(),random_int())
print a.b,a.c,a.d
```

imports :

```
from collections import namedtuple
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return any object, including list and tuple that may be upacked on assignment:

```
import random

def random_ints():
    return random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100)

a, b = random_ints()
print(b, a)
```

in fact this `a, b` is a shortcut for tuple as well, when you do multiple assignment the comma separated list of variables on the left is tuple too and could be written as:

(a, b) = range(2)

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite would be to convert your function to a generator (provided that it it fits well into your program).

**Example:**

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> def rnd_numbers(how_many=1):  # assuming how_many is positive
...     for _ in range(how_many):  # use xrange() in Python2.x
...         yield random.randint(1, 100)
... 
>>> x, y, z = rnd_numbers(3)
>>> x
98
>>> y
69
>>> z
16
>>> a,b = rnd_numbers(2)
>>> a
52
>>> b
33
```